# One SQL query instead of many

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a MySQL table with just 2 columns:

```
id
invited_by_id
```

and I want to know for 
each id how many times it appears in `invited_by_id` column.

How to make this using only one query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple `GROUP BY` on the `invited_by_id` column is all you need, since it holds the same id values as the `id` column:

```
SELECT invited_by_id, COUNT(*) AS invited_count FROM table GROUP BY invited_by_id
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select id1.id, (count*)
from id as id1
inner join id as id2 on id1.id = id2.invited_by_id
group by id1.id
```

Comment: Michael's is more efficient unless you have to worry about values in invited_by_id that are not in id.

Answer (score 1):

```
select invited_by_id, count(*) from table group by invited_by_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT m.id
     , grp.cnt
FROM 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT id
      FROM mytable
    ) AS m
  LEFT JOIN
      ( SELECT invited_by_id
             , COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM mytable
        GROUP BY invited_by_id
      ) AS grp
    ON grp.invited_by_id = m.id
```